How can i Add e-sign in an attached PDF Odoo14
i'm using Odoo14 CE, i add
class dossier(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'purchase.order'
    ​Proformat_fournisseur = fields.Binary(string="Proformat fournisseur", attachment=True, index=True, tracking=1, store=True)

so user can add proformat (sent by the supplier) in the purchase order, user should confirm the purchase, e-sign that proformat already sent by the supplier and saved in th field  "Proformat_fournisseur"
I already scanned the signature of the user, i can add it in the qweb report generated by Odoo such the purchase order report, but the signature should be on the buttom of the proformat sent by the supplier. so user can send it to supplier by mail later.
I set the report_purchasequotation_document to this just to test it:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="purchase.report_purchasequotation_document">
   <t t-call="web.basic_layout">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                <div class="page">
                    <t t-if="doc.Proformat_fournisseur">
                        <!-- Embed the Proformat PDF -->
                        <div>
                            <iframe
                                t-att-src="'data:application/pdf;base64,' + doc.Proformat_fournisseur.decode('utf-8')"
                                style="width: 100%; height: 1000px; border: none;">
                            </iframe>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
</t>


i expected it will print the PDF stored in Proformat_fournisseur, but i got just an empty page.
i'm open to other suggestions !
thank you for reading.

do you mean it can not be done, as i need it ?

 that doesn't do it ?
Note: i added this funtion
def encode_pdf_to_base64(pdf_path):
with open(pdf_path, "rb") as pdf_file:
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read())
return encoded_string.decode('utf-8')
and
def encode_pdf_and_save(self, pdf_path):
encoded_pdf = encode_pdf_to_base64(pdf_path)
self.Proformat_fournisseur = encoded_pdf
so i'm sure the file is saved into base64 and now when printing i got a pdf containing illisible texts like :
"JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0........." when convert it with online tool from base64 to file i got the correct PDF

yes it does print images like PNG and JPEG

OK, thank you very much for time and efforts
